# Parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Tags: php, xml

Eu consigo entender bem o *script*, exceto pela parte que ele trabalha o **XML**... então não sei dizer se o erro é no *script*, ou no **XML** que ele tenta obter.

**Código:**

```
<?php
 require ("includes/connection.php");
 require ("includes/start-session.php");
 require ("includes/encript.php");
?>
<?php
header("access-control-allow-origin: https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br");

$email = 'email@sandboxpagseguro';
$token = 'tokensandbox';

$pagamento = $_GET['transaction_id'];
$url = 'https://ws.sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/transactions/'. $pagamento .'?email=' .$email. '&token=' .$token;

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$transaction= curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($transaction == 'Unauthorized'){
    //Caso o token ou e-mail não sejam validados pelo PagSeguro.
    echo 'Unauthorized'; 
    exit;
}
$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
if($transaction->code > 0) {
$transaction_id = $transaction->code;
$client_id = $transaction->reference;        
    $payment_type = $transaction->paymentMethod->type;
    if($payment_type == 1){ 
        $payment_method = "Cartão de crédito";
    } elseif($payment_type == 2){ 
        $payment_method = "Boleto";
    } elseif($payment_type == 3){ 
        $payment_method = "Débito online (TEF)"; 
    } else { 
        $payment_method = "Outro"; 
    }
    $payment_type_method = $transaction->type;
        if($payment_type_method == 1){ 
        $payment_method_transiction = "Pagamento";
    } elseif($payment_type_method == 11){ 
        $payment_method_transiction = "Assinatura";
    } else { 
        $payment_method_transiction = "Outro"; 
    }

    $parceled = $transaction->installmentCount;
    $parceled_value = $transaction->installmentFeeAmount;
    $product = $transaction->items->item->id;
    $product_value = $transaction->items->item->amount;
    $transaction_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($transaction->date));
    $transaction_date_last = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($transaction->lastEventDate));
    if($transaction->status == 1){
        $transaction_status = 'Aguardando pagamento';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 2){
        $transaction_status = 'Em análise';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 3){ // :)
        $transaction_status = 'Paga';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 4){ // :D
        $transaction_status = 'Disponível';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 5){
        $transaction_status = 'Em disputa';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 6){
        $transaction_status = 'Devolvida';
    } elseif($transaction->status == 7){
        $transaction_status = 'Cancelada';
    }   
    $client_name = $transaction->sender->name;

    // Faz a inserção no BD.
    $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `payments`(`transaction_id`, `client_id`, `payment_method`, `payment_method_transiction`, `transaction_status`, `transaction_date`, `transaction_date_last`, `product`, `product_value`, `client_name`) VALUES ('$transaction_id', '$client_id', '$payment_method', '$payment_method_transiction', '$transaction_status', '$transaction_date', '$transaction_date_last', '$product', '$product_value', '$client_name')");
    if ($insert) {
        echo 'dados inseridos';
    } else {
        echo 'falha na inserção dos dados.';
    }
} else {
    echo $transaction->code;
}
?>
```

**Parse Error:**

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/u657579475/public_html/loja/confirm.php on line 26
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Forbidden in
>   /home/u657579475/public_html/loja/confirm.php on line 26
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in
>   /home/u657579475/public_html/loja/confirm.php on line 26

**Linha 26:**

```
$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
```

Comment: Dá uma olhadinha em: https://github.com/gabrielsbarros/pagseguro/blob/master/PagSeguro.php Você vai precisar usar `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` para suprimir possíveis erros no XML.

Comment: Ai é só fazer a call do script php via require? e inserir esse código antes da conversão do xml pra objeto?

Comment: Sim. Na verdade o ideal é usar um `autoload`, mas funciona perfeitamente com `require`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa mensagem de erro é tipicamente causada por má formatação do XML.

Verifique se o conteúdo de `$transaction` contém uma string XML válida.

Para testar, nesse trecho

```
$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
```

Troque por isso:

```
echo $transaction; exit;
$transaction = simplexml_load_string($transaction);
```

Isso não é a solução do problema. É apenas uma técnica de depuração para encontrar as causas do problema mais facilmente.

Execute e veja o resultado no código HTML gerado. Pressione CTRL+U caso esteja usando o Google Chrome.

O intuito é ler o conteúdo da variável `$transaction`.

Caso não saiba interpretar o XML visualmente, poste o resultado do teste na sua pergunta.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso.

Comment: Daniel, o resultado foi: Forbidden.

Comment: esse é o problema...  corrija a conexão com a api